# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {message: PERMISSION_DENIED,)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

Here is my cloud function

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log(`Hi ${data}`);
  return `Hi there ${data["name"]}`;
});
```

Here is my code in flutter on button click

```
final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance
        .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'addUser')
          ..timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);

 try {
                      final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable
                          .call(<String, dynamic>{"name": "Pritish"});
                      debugPrint(result.data);
                    } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
                      debugPrint('caught generic exception');
                      debugPrint(
                          "${e.message.toString()} ${e.code.toString()} ${e.details.toString()} ${e.toString()}");
                    }
```

But i keep getting following error `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {message: PERMISSION_DENIED, details: null, code: PERMISSION_DENIED})`

I am not accessing any of the `firestore` database data so why is it showing permission error. Also i am using other services of `firebase` like `auth,signin, firestore,storage` and they seem to work fine for me. I have deployed the function correctly as well. I have other functions for FCM as well and they seem to be working fine. The setup for Android for Firebase is done correctly as well

Comment: If you're unable to resolve this by making sure your Firebase CLI is at the latest version, and deleting and redeploying the function, please contact Firebase support directly. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it on **web**. Not sure whether you're running it on mobile or web, but I'm pretty sure your firebase configuration is either wrong or absent.

Please also take a note that you didn't provide `region` for your function.

```
  final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'XYZ',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        databaseURL: "https://xyz.firebaseio.com",
        projectID: "xyz",
        storageBucket: "xyz.appspot.com",
        gcmSenderID: "123456789",
        googleAppID: "1:1213123:web:23904832948",
        trackingID: "G-XYZXYZ123"),
  );

  CloudFunctions(app: app, region: "europe-west2")
      .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'addUser')
      .call({'user': user})
      .catchError((error, stack) => print("Error $error\n$stack"))
      .asStream()
      .listen((event) {
        print("Success ${event.data}");
      });
```